# Override Backbone.sync for Rails API authentication with Devise

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, devise, rails-api

I am trying to override backbone's .sync method in order to have authentication working for my Rails API. I have been going off of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483894/what-is-the-best-way-to-user-authentication-with-devise-3-and-backbone) and I feel like I am really close to figuring it out. I have the rails side set up but I am having trouble on the front end of things. I am stuck on the part in the other post where he has

```
var token = YourAppName.csrfToken;
```

I am not too sure what to substitute for 'YourAppName'. Here is the backbone code I have so far. My app is called 'Droppin' and when I sub it in I get errors saying it isn't defined.

```
// overide backbone.sync
Backbone._sync = Backbone.sync;

Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
  if (!options.noCSRF) {
    var beforeSend = options.beforeSend;

    // Set X-CSRF-Token HTTP header
    options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
      var token = Droppin.csrfToken;  
      if (token) xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);

      // this will include session information in the requests
      xhr.withCredentials = true;

      if (beforeSend) return beforeSend.apply(this, arguments);
    };
  }

  var complete = options.complete;
  options.complete = function(jqXHR, textStatus) {

     // If response includes CSRF token we need to remember it
     var token = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('X-CSRF-Token') 
     if (token) Droppin.csrfToken = token;

     model.trigger('sync:end');
     if (complete) complete(jqXHR, textStatus);
  };

  // Serialize data, optionally using paramRoot
  if (options.data == null && model && (method === 'create' || method === 'update' || method === 'patch')) {
    options.contentType = 'application/json';
    data = JSON.stringify(options.attrs || model.toJSON(options));
    if (model.paramRoot) {
      data = {};
      data[model.paramRoot] = model.toJSON(options);
    } else {
      data = model.toJSON();
    }
    options.data = JSON.stringify(data);
  }

  return Backbone._sync(method, model, options);
};
```

What do I need to do in order to grab that CSRF token and have it properly attached to the HTTP header? I should also mention that I am using require.js and am handling the override in the main.js file (not sure if that is the right place to do it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined `Dropping` somewhere else in your code beforehand? For example,

```
window.Droppin = window.Dropping || {};
```

If not, when you try to execute `var token = Droppin.csrfToken;` Droppin will be undefined and thus won't have the attribute `csrfToken`

Comment: No I have not, I am also using require.js so how would I get this Droppin object across all of my files? And by the way I was taking care of this override inside of the main.js file for require, is that the right place to do that in?

Comment: Even though you are using `requirejs` global variables are still available. You should have `Droppin = Dropping || {};` as one of the first statements in your `main.js`. As for the best place to do this: I haven't used requirejs in a long time but I would put the initialization code in a different module and then `require` it in `main.js`. Just my opinion but I would use [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) instead of require.js. Fewer headaches in my experience.

Comment: Just to be clear, you wouldn't be using `requirejs` to access Dropping. It would be in the global scope, so you can access it anywhere. You certainly could put it in it's module but you don't have to.

Comment: So I just tried your approach but it is still giving errors saying Droppin is not defined at the line where I have 

    `Droppin = Droppin || {};`

Comment: I changed it to just `Droppin = {};` and it seems to be working. Thanks for your help. I am going to try the rest of it out tomorrow.

Comment: My mistake, it should be `window.Droppin = window.Droppin || {}`