# How to check user logged in and make Backbone get/post to Rails backend? (+Devise)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, devise

I have a Rails backend which uses Devise, and a decoupled Backbone frontend on a separate site.

I'd like to have Backbone make `GET` calls to the separate Rails server to my Items resource.  Based on:

1. If user is not logged in, make the `GET` call with some default parameters
2. If user is logged in, make the `GET` call with `user.attribute` as a parameter

I also want to allow the user to `POST` to edit account details (e.g., `user.attribute`).

---

How do I:

1. Check if user is logged in / allow user to log in from Backbone or separate Rails site
2. Pull the logged-in user's attribute
3. Verify authenticity when `POST`ing

**TL;DR How to share a session between Devise and Backbone? How to make calls using that session? Is session sharing the right structure?**

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483894/what-is-the-best-way-to-user-authentication-with-devise-3-and-backbone) and my understanding thus far is:

- Backbone passes user's login information in a `GET` to Devise `/signin`
- Rails sends a session cookie back and other stuff that I somehow save in Backbone somewhere
- Each time Backbone makes `GET` or `POST` calls, I use that session cookie and other stuff? and Rails/Devise verifies it somehow

Thanks in advance -

Answer (score 0):

It's best for the front end to initially assume that the user is logged in, make the request, and for the server to fail the request back with a 401, 403, or similar response code, indicating to the front end that the users is not authenticated. The front end should then make whatever calls are necessary to authenticate the user, and then reissue the original request(s) for the user as appropriate.